# SkiaSharp violates Windows Store App Certification

Tags: uwp, skiasharp

Just finished creating a great UWP app using SkiaSharp. Ive tried running the App Store Certification Kit, but I get the following voilations:

```
Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
API TlsAlloc in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. libSkiaSharp.dll calls this API.
API TlsGetValue in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. libSkiaSharp.dll calls this API.
API TlsSetValue in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. libSkiaSharp.dll calls this API.
Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps violates the Windows Store certification requirements.
```

So, does anyone know if we can publish to the Windows App Store with SkiaSharp ? if not the UWP support doesnt make any sense.

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the issue has been solved by someone on the Xamarin forums.
Basically the SkiaSharp library currently calls the wrong framework members, and its just a bug in the current nuget packages - so should get fixed really soon.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/211510

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using SkiaSharp!

I have been hard at work getting UWP support finished, and I think I have done it. The last two releases: v1.53.1 and v1.53.1.1 should not cause any certification errors.

Please open an issue (https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues) if this is still the case so we can fix it ASAP.

**EDIT**

We are hashing this out here: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/129

*last note: ARM/x64 are OK, but x86 was still using `getenv`*

**EDIT 2**

> **Your submission for Skia.UWP.Demo passed certification.**
>
> It will take up to 16 hours for your changes to be visible to all of your customers. Once published, your app's listing will be available at https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NBLGGH51856.
>
> Thank you, 
>   The Windows Store Team